# Get a javascript variable to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a code where I have to put PHP variables in JS and other way around in the same file.

From PHP to JS is no problem, but from JS to PHP is a little bit more  difficult.

Maybe you can help.

```
<?php 
 if($freischaltung==1){
?>
<tr><th><a type="button" name="msg" href="Nachrichten.php?ID=<?php echo $id; ?>">Nachricht senden</a></th></tr> 
<tr><th>
<?php 
  } else {
?>
<button onclick="freischalten()">Freischalten</button>
<p id="FreischaltungAusgabe"></p>
<?php
   echo "<script>
    var krone =".$kronen.";
   </script>";
?>          
<script>
  function freischalten() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Das Freischalten kostet dich 2 Kronen!") == true) {
        krone = krone -2;
        if(krone<2){
          x = "Du hast zu wenige Kronen um eine Freischaltung durchzuführen!";
         document.getElementById("FreischaltungAusgabe").innerHTML = x;
        } else {
         x = "Erfolgreich freigeschaltet! Restliche Kronen = "+krone;
         $freischalten = 1; // This should be a PHP Variable
         //Also I want to do at this part a INSERT INTO friends Where....
        document.getElementById("FreischaltungAusgabe").innerHTML = x;
      }
    } else {
     x = "Vielleicht beim nächsten mal!";
     document.getElementById("FreischaltungAusgabe").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to get the $freischalten variable as a PHP variable outside of the JS. Also I want to insert it into a table at this part.

Comment: Your design is... basically wrong. When you need to mix JS and PHP like this, you should go back to the drawing table and rethink what you're doing. Probably, what you should do is to keep the js (well, no, you should make sure your js is in a single, external file, and capture clicks/events in the js, not using onclick and similar things), and use AJAX to send/receive info to/from PHP.

Comment: you can save the value via ajax and save it into session, or try to save it the cookies

Comment: you should send the value by ajax to a proper  php code file

Comment: php lives on the server, javascript lives in the browser(actually any Web client like mobile phone or even desktop), when you want to communicate them you send/recieve HTTP requests/responses :)

Answer (score 0):

JS is a client side language and PHP is server side language. You can't set JS variable directly to PHP variable. Use hidden form or Ajax to get JS variable in a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that what you want to do is possible but you have to reload the page, either using an ajax call ou refreshing the role page.

Webpages are static by default and after the browser loads your page it is presented as is, you can activate javascript and other things, but to parse a JS variable to PHP you have to submit a form or use an Ajax call to another php script and return the result to your current page.

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp):

AJAX is a developer s dream, because you can:

- Update a web page without reloading the page
- Request data from a server - after the page has loaded
- Receive data from a server - after the page has loaded
- Send data to a server - in the background

You should do something like this, in your main php form:

```
function parseVariable() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // the element this.responseText will be all the content returned by your php script called by the xhttp.open
     document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  // the method can be either GET or POST
  xhttp.open("GET", "myphpscript.php?myvariable=" + document.getElementById("myfield").value , true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

After that you must call the `parseVariable()` function in your HTML, using javascript.

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" id="myfield">
<button type="button" onclick="parseVariable()">Parse</button>
<p id="myelement">&nbsp;</p>
```

In your `myphpscript.php` you will handle the call as a GET method to receive "myfield" text content, do the things you need to do and echo your result back to the main page. Let's say you will receive your variable and add 10 to it and return it to the main page.

```
<?php 

$result = $_GET["myvariable"]; //GET the JAVASCRIPT variable into PHP
$result = $result + 10;
echo $result; 
?>
```